# Tried Reinstalling PulseAudio now no sound at all Lubuntu 17.04

Tags: sound, lubuntu, pulseaudio, hdmi, 17.04

I has audio working through the computer only, then I hooked up my laptop to my computer to get a HDMI connection. No sound came through. Tried to purge and reinstall PulseAudio now I have no sound at all or a volume icon. "Establishing connection to pulse audio" error is now showing up when I try to open PulseAudio. Any suggestions? Lubuntu 17.04 is the OS.

Comment: Terminal when I try to run pavucontrol "(pavucontrol:1755): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-lubuntu.css:66:13: The :insensitive pseudo-class is deprecated. Use :disabled instead."

Comment: Please edit your question with the exact comamnds you use to purge and reinatall PulseAudio

Comment: sudo apt-get purge pulse audio

Comment: sudo apt-get auto clean

Comment: sudo apt-get autoremove

Comment: user:~$ pavucontrol

(pavucontrol:1678): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-lubuntu.css:66:13: The :insensitive pseudo-class is deprecated. Use :disabled instead.